# Simulate Winforms Button Click Animation

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a button and inside my button I have an image control.  When the users click on the image I'd like to animate the button so it appears the button was pressed.  I don't really care whether the actual button press event fires or not--it's the illusion of a button press I want to see.

Note: the only options I see on the web involve writing directly to the Windows API--a level of complexity and non-upgradability I really don't want to get into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my picturbox look like a button by giving it a raised border style.  Then on the mouseclick event I simulate the look of a button press by changing the border style for a few hundred miliseconds.

```
Private Sub simulateButtonPress(ByRef pictureBox As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraPictureBox)
    pictureBox.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.Inset
    Application.DoEvents()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400)
    pictureBox.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.Raised
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually found a much better solution--put the Insert in the MouseDown invent and the Raised int he MouseUp event--then it's tied to how long the mouse button is pressed down.  (Just like real buttons works). This also prevents having a second click take place while the first simulated click is still running.

Comment: You didn't mention in the question that you're using Infragistics controls. Their WinButton doesn't do the image handling you're looking for‽

Comment: It does support images, but not the resizing capabilities I needed.  (This particular application needed to be able to smoothly maximize on a wide range of screen resolutions)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use two different images, one for a normal state, and another for when your button is being pressed.

If you want to go for more complicated route try using GDI+. Here is a quick [sample tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/simpleaquabutton.aspx) on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an image control inside your button control instead of using the [button control's Image property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx)?

Using the Image property of the button will give you a button with an image that the user can press and that will raise the OnClick event without doing any extra work or re-implementing features that are already available.

Comment: I tried that, but the image stretch functionality wasn't sufficient to handle what I wanted.