# WinForms: How do I simulate button behavior on an image?

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have an extension of the winforms TabControl, it's draws an X on each tab to allow the user to close the tab.

[image]

Compare that to the standard:

[image]

How can I simulate button look&feel on that image?  What I mean is, when the user clicks down, it should visually indicate that.  A button does this with an inset image. For bonus points, I'd like to do the hover part, too - where the image will "light up" whn the mouse hovers.

But the X isn't a button, and it's not PictureBox control.  It's not a control at all.  It's just been drawn there.

Is there a way to draw an inset border on MouseDown and Raised on MouseUp? Would I be better off generating another image, for the "inset" phase? (and another for the hover).

anyone done this before?

---

> Related: [Simulate Winforms Button Click Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196571/simulate-winforms-button-click-animation)
>   But this question is different because he actually has a PictureBox control.  I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have just drawn it there then you need to do the following:

- Have an onmouseover / onleftclick event for the parent control.  This may be the form itself, or tab control.
- In that function check to see if the mouse is over where you draw the image.
- If it is over where you draw the image, then show the "click" or "hover" state.

I've cobbled together some code as to how it may look

```
myControl.MouseClick += new EventHandler(myClickHandler);

private void myClickHandler(EventArgs e)
{
//Check e to see if left button was pressed
//Check e location to see if mouse is in correct location, i.e. over the "X"
//If so then alter a state variable i.e. tabstates[0] = TabStates.HOVER;
}

private void myDrawingFunc()
{
//Draw X
if (tabstates[0] == TabStates.HOVER)
{
//Draw hover state
}
else
{
//Draw other state
}
}
```

This is obviously just an example but indicates roughly how you would do this.  Note I added `tabstates` as an array or list to allow you to have a state for each tab.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  In the end I decided to not bother to provide a visual cue for the click.  Instead I provided the "hover" effect.  it basically followed your advice, using OnMouseMove rather than OnMouseClick.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `ButtonRenderer` class.  It can be used to draw standard looking buttons.

Comment: I've been using that, but it's really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use images instead of drawing the whole close button, it would be much easier to use, for example imagine you have 3 states for the button (MouseUp, MouseDown, Pressed) which must be declared as an enum, and in the event handlers of your custom control just need to change the enum to MouseDown, MouseUp or Pressed.

While painting your custom Control on OnPaint check the enum and draw the image.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers.  That gave me some good ideas.

I wanted a "button" sort of behavior, with hover effects and display.  In the end I settled for the hover, and skipped the inset display.    The look and feel of that did what I wanted, especially considering the button just closes a tab.

---

Here's how I did it.

1. In the custom TabControl class, embed 3 images: Close, Close-Grey, and Close-Hover. Read these images in at time of construction, from the resource stream.

   Inside the PaintImage() method, select the image to use, depending on the state of the "button".
2. Now, to change states of the button: override OnMouseMove and OnMouseLeave.

   In OnMouseMove, test if the MouseEventArgs.Location is on the "hot spot" of the X for the selected tab.  If so, enable a System.Timers.Timer, with an interval of 110ms. (or so)  The timer fires when the mouse stops moving, and it is positioned over the X.  If OnMouseMove detects the mouse is not over the X, then disable the timer, and if necessary, paint the X.

   In the Elapsed event on that timer, set the image state to "Hover". Paint the image. In my case it turns from dark gray to red.

   In the OnMouseLeave method, set the image state to "Close" (normal). Paint the image.  This is to handle the case where the mouse quickly exits the control after hovering on the image. In my case it turns from red to drak gray.

   If the image gets painted for any other reason, it will be painted properly according to the state.
3. To make the "button" active, Override OnMouseClick .

   In that method, just call TabPages.Remove().  If you wanna get fancy, fire a BeforeTabClose event to notify the application, and to allow it to suppress or cancel the action.